# real and imaginary parts of complex expression

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

How can I find the real and imaginary parts of:
$$
\sqrt{(a+ib)^2+c}
$$
where $a,b,c$ are real.  If $c=0$, then the answer is trivial, but I'm having trouble doing this for $c\neq 0$.

Comment: Transform it to exponential form. Do calcs there. Transform the result to 'm+in'  form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you could write the inner expression as X+iY, it's better to focus on generally evaluating $\sqrt{X+iY} $

Writing it as a complex number

L+iM=$\sqrt{X+iY} $

You can then square it, and then compare the real and imaginary parts separately, solving which should give you upto 2 possible square roots

Comment: What do you mean by $1+im$?  Can you please show more steps?  If so, I'll gladly mark as answer.  Thanks

Comment: It was lowercase L :)